# VIM Adenture Level 9 question

Tags: vim-adventures

I am stuck at the Level 9 "Hai can has studio" puzzle being on BI[CG][GK]ER with 3 strokes left. Would love to have 'R' (ie. replace mode) but I don't have it. Did I miss it somewhere in the older levels?

Answer (score 2):

I just re-read the original question.  The correct answer is:  Yes, **r** (replace mode) is in Level 4.

[image: Vim-Adventures level 4 screenshot locating the r key]

After that -- Level 9 "Hai can has stdio" -- I'll omit several editing tasks (since the original poster must have done those successfully) and skip to the last one.

- After deleting the 5-lines block, you are on the 'I' in 'IZ'.
- Use **f C** (no spaces) to get to your 'BI[CG][GK]ER' target with 3 keypresses remaining.
- Use **2 r G** to finish the edit.
- A yellow key appears.  Get back to solid ground with **17 B** or whatever works for you.

Answer (score -1):

Just verified: `5~` should do the trick. (Hovering the cursor on the N and you should be good to go.)